# VM (Hyper-V) into AD (non-virtual)

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v

I have trouble getting my VMs into the domain.

Several old machines functioned as "servers" in our environment and when I newly started working here, I wanted to change this cluster into something more appropriate. So I calculated how one big server would cost us a certain amount of money but we would save it in electricity-bills etc.

The server finally arrived (HP Proliant) and I installed a Server 2008 R2 on it (boss wont pay for something newer a.k.a. more expensive). I created .vhd files of the HDDs of the servers I want to virtualize and copied those files into the new server. I activated Hyper-V role and created a new VM and selected one of the .vhd files as the HDD for that VM and started the machine. The machine starts, all goody.

As far as I understand in Hyper-V we got 3 network-settings and for my purpose "external network" is the one to go with. Correct me if I'm wrong. The server is already in the domain. So I thought it should actually work already, but somehow I cannot connect to the domain.

The network settings on the VM is DHCP but it is not getting an IP from the DC. Do I need to spoof the old MAC-Address? Do I have to turn the physical machine that I'm virtualizing off? (I didn't do that because I wanted to check first whether I can get both running at the same time before turning it off. Also I cannot access the environment past business hours, so testing this is when nobody is around is kinda out of question)

The VM has W7 running on it, if it matters. I'm kinda lost what to do as I only find how to join a VM into a virtual network when I try to google for solutions.

DC (physical, x.x.x.1 IP), The new server (physical, x.x.x.82 IP), The VM (virtual, DHCP, current address of its physical copy x.x.x.123 though DHCP is set on it, 123 is just the IP it got).

Regards

Edit: Found the solution. The server has 2 NICs. "Connection" and "Connection 2" or whatever it is called by standard in English. The virtual adapter (3rd NIC so to say) has "Connection 2" in its description too. I got confused and addressed the wrong NIC in the Hyper-V options. I am editing this from the VM that finally has connection to the domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Has been resolved. Answer is in the edit of original post.